# Bash multiple rename in one line: is possible?

Tags: bash, rename

Is possible to rename and substitute on fly with bash?
for example i have

```
  VTS_01_1.VOB  VTS_01_2.VOB  VTS_01_3.VOB
```

I want to rename for use in mencoder with

```
movie_1.avi movie_2.avi,etc..
```

I know how to substitute VTS,but not VOB.

```
for i in  VTS_01_[1-4]*B;do echo ${i/VTS_0?_?.VOB/Movie}.avi;done
```

give me

```
Movie.avi
Movie.avi
Movie.avi
Movie.avi
```

i want

```
Movie_1.avi
Movie_2.avi
Movie_3.avi
Movie_4.avi
```

Comment: Feel free to use perlexpr with `rename` command .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in two steps e.g. first remove the extension, then substitute the `VTS_01` prefix:

```
$ for i in VTS_01_[1-4]*B; do b="${i%.VOB}"; echo "${b/VTS_01/Movie}.avi"; done
Movie_1.avi
Movie_2.avi
Movie_3.avi
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [rename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) program. It uses perl expression. How ever here we have no complex expression.

In this case you can use this:

```
rename VTS_01 movie VTS_01*VOB
```

Comment: Be aware that there are at least two different programs called `rename`, and they use very different syntax for expressing how to map the original names to new names.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use python? Something like

```
$ ipython
In [1]: import os
In [2]: all_files = os.listdir(".")
In [3]: for filename in all_files:
In [4]:     newname = 'Movie' + filename[6:9] + 'avi'
In [5]:     os.rename(filename, newname)
```

should solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

BIngo!

```
for i in  VTS_01_[1-4]*B;do echo mv $i  "$(echo $i|sed 's/VTS/Movie/g;s/VOB/avi/g')";done
```

Is more useful with commands like mencoder,etc

Comment: You should really accept [steeldriver's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159331/6761); it showed you the structure to use and is cleaner (no additional process called).